# How can I make this multi-threaded Python pinger faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, performance, optimization

My goal: I want to ping every single IPv4 address and record whether or not they responded.

The way I have it set up is every IP address corresponds to an index. For example 0.0.0.0 is index 0 and 0.0.1.0 is index 256. So if 0.0.0.0 responded, then the 0th element of the bitarray is true.

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
from bitarray import bitarray
import threading
import time

response_array = bitarray(256 * 256 * 256 * 256)
response_array.setall(False)

def send_all_pings():
    index = 0
    for f1 in range(256):
        for f2 in range(256):
            for f3 in range(256):
                for f4 in range(256):
                    thread = PingerThread(".".join(map(str, [f1, f2, f3, f4])), index)
                    thread.start()
                    index += 1

    time.sleep(30)
    print("Writing response array to file")
    with open('responses.bin', 'wb') as out:
        response_array.tofile(out)


class PingerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, address, index):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.index = index

    def run(self):
        if subprocess.call(["ping", "-c", "1", "-w", "1", self.address]) == 0:
            response_array[self.index] = True
        else:
            response_array[self.index] = False
```

What can I do to make this run faster? Any optimisations at all, even if very small, are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: The best form of optimization is the one that isn't to do with code: narrow your scope! You probably already know but there's no scenario in which you'd ever ping all the billions of IP addresses. Limit the scope of the network first and then see if you're happy with the execution time :)

Comment: `nmap` has functionality to scan large address ranges…

Answer (score 0):

a few suggestions, roughly in order of benefits:

1. try not to start a "fork bomb": your code tries to start 4 billion threads that each spawn a process.  this will bring any computer to its knees, you need to limit yourself to (at most) a few hundred processes at any one time
2. write the networking code yourself.  starting a whole thread & process up to send & receive a single network packet has an enormous overhead
3. you're almost certainly IO limited not CPU, use an asyncio library

assuming you've written code capable of sending out 10k packets per second, this will still take you ~5 days.  it wouldn't surprise me if your ISP blocks you pretty quickly if you really do start doing thing, or at least severely rate limits/charges you for data incurred

if you send out too many pings you won't get responses, they're "unreliable" by design